# How to prevent user logging out when refreshing the page in an Angular(Client) and Loopback(Server) application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback.io SPA with an Angular client. I followed the official Loopback Documentation https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Create-AngularJS-client.html
The problem is that when I refresh the page in the browser, the client is logging out. It seems that the currentUser variable is not restored after the refresh. How could I solve this?

Here are the auth.js and app.js files:

**js/services/auth.js**

```js
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('AuthService', ['Reviewer', '$q', '$rootScope', function(User, $q,
    $rootScope) {
    function login(email, password) {
      return User
        .login({
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        .$promise
        .then(function(response) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = {
            id: response.user.id,
            tokenId: response.id,
            email: email
          };
        });
    }

    function logout() {
      return User
        .logout()
        .$promise
        .then(function() {
          $rootScope.currentUser = null;
        });
    }

    function register(email, password) {
      return User
        .create({
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        .$promise;
    }
    return {
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register
    };
  }]);
```

**client/js/app.js**

```js
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'lbServices'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,
    $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('add-review', {
        url: '/add-review',
        templateUrl: 'views/review-form.html',
        controller: 'AddReviewController',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('all-reviews', {
        url: '/all-reviews',
        templateUrl: 'views/all-reviews.html',
        controller: 'AllReviewsController'
      })
      .state('edit-review', {
        url: '/edit-review/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/review-form.html',
        controller: 'EditReviewController',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('delete-review', {
        url: '/delete-review/:id',
        controller: 'DeleteReviewController',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('forbidden', {
        url: '/forbidden',
        templateUrl: 'views/forbidden.html',
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthLoginController'
      })
      .state('logout', {
        url: '/logout',
        controller: 'AuthLogoutController'
      })
      .state('my-reviews', {
        url: '/my-reviews',
        templateUrl: 'views/my-reviews.html',
        controller: 'MyReviewsController',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('sign-up', {
        url: '/sign-up',
        templateUrl: 'views/sign-up-form.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController',
      })
      .state('sign-up-success', {
        url: '/sign-up/success',
        templateUrl: 'views/sign-up-success.html'
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('all-reviews');
  }])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      // redirect to login page if not logged in
      if (next.authenticate && !$rootScope.currentUser) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent current page from loading
        $state.go('forbidden');
      }
    });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

scope in angularjs after refresh page initial, and not save old value before refresh
you can save token in local storage browser (or cookie) and in load page set scope